# How to use Java Arrays.sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am learning about how `Arrays.sort(...)` works in Java.

Why are variables: `temp` and `dopas` both sorted after the only sorting `temp`?

```
System.out.println("Before");
for (int i = 0; i < POP; i++)
  System.out.println(dopas[i]+"");           //dopas is unsorted

System.out.println("After");
float[] temp=dopas;
Arrays.sort(temp);                           //sort temp

for (int i = 0; i < POP; i++)
  System.out.println(temp[i]+" "+dopas[i]);  //Both temp and dopas are now sorted
```

I expected dopas to remain unsorted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Arrays are objects in Java, therefore when using array variables you are actually using references to arrays.

Thus the line

```
float[] temp=dopas;
```

will only copy the *reference* to array `dopas`. Afterwards,  `dopas` and  `temp` point to the same array, hence both will appear sorted after using `sort()`.

Use `System.arrayCopy` or `Arrays.copyOf` to create a copy of the array.

Answer (score 7):

your assignment: `float[] temp=dopas;` is actually just copying a reference to the array. What I think you want to do is `float[] temp = dopas.clone();`

Answer (score 6):

`temp` simply is a reference to `dopas`. There actually is only one array in memory.

If you want `temp` to be a copy of `dopas`, try:

```
float[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(dopas, dopas.length);
```

This way, you will *deep copy* your array instead of *shallow copying* it!

Answer (score 3):

Because in Java, you access arrays *by-reference*, not *by-value*.

So `temp` and `dopas` are both references to the same array.

Answer (score 3):

> Why after Array.sort both arrays are sorted?

Because there is only one array.  `float[] temp=dopas;` does not create a new array or copy the existing arrays contents.  It simply copies an array **reference** ... so that you have the reference to the same array in two places.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign `temp` the value of `dopas`, it doesn't make a copy, it makes the variables refer to the same array.

Answer (score 2):

Because temp and dopas (what we call a variable) are pointers to a space in memory. By using the code

```
float[] temp = dopas
```

you just say let "temp" point to the same space in memory as dopas does. So the result is that you have two pointers to the same space in memory. And by sorting temp you're sorting the contents of that space so by referencing dopas later in youre code you're accessing the exact same data.

PS: Dogmatixed mentioned a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because both arrays temp and dopas are the same. Assignment `temp=dopas;` assigns reference to array. It does not copy its content. This is the reason why when you sort the first you sort the second too.

Answer (score 1):

`dopas` and `temp` refer to the same array and can be used interchangeably.

```
float[] temp=dopas;
```

After this line, `temp[i]` will be exactly the same as `dopas[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because temp and dopas are two references to the same array

Answer (score 1):

temp is referencing dopas ,so when dopas gets sorted so does temp.They are in fact pointing to the same array.hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

temp and dopas share the same pointer, since you don't create a new instance of array, you just assign the same pointer.

Answer (score 0):

*temp* and *dopas* are referencing the same array.

if you want temp to act like a new array, then use **clone()** method.

```
float[] temp = dopas.clone();
```

clone() method creates a new array and copies the contents of the dopas to the newly created array.