# Return variable and array from function java

Tags: java, function, sorting, return

I have a sorting function. I want to return two values and i thought it will be better if i return vaiable and array. But i don't know how to do it.

```
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] allatal)
{
    //En variabel för att man ska lagra info i den 
    //Tillfällig lagring. 
    int temp;

    //Variabel för förlyttningar
    int forFlyttningar = 0;

    //Loopar, loopen är inte mer än storleken på arrayen
    for(int i=0;i<allatal.length-1;i++ )
    {
       //En till loop
       for(int j=i+1;j<allatal.length;j++)
        { 
           //Om talet peckaren pekar på större än det andra
           //talet så ska programmet
           if (allatal[i] > allatal[j])
           {
               //Lagrar värdet array "i" i temp 
               temp = allatal[i];
               //Överför "j" till "i"
               allatal[i] = allatal[j];
               //temp värdet överförs till "i"
               allatal[j] = temp;
               forFlyttningar++;
            }
         }
    }
    return allatal, forFlyttningar;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Either return it as an array with two elements, or create a custom object for returning those two particular elements.

```
public class Result {
    public int forFlyttningar;
    public int[] allatal;

    public Result(int forFlyttningar, int[] allatal) {}
}

// Snip
return new Result(forFlyttningar, allatal);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use either an object to save the array and the value, or you can return 
vector contains both array and value,
but best practices is to use an object

Answer (score 0):

The Java framework does not allow for such a thing. However, you can (either one will do):

- Create a wrapper class, which takes an array and and integer. In your method, create an instance of this wrapper class with whatever values you want to return and yield that.
- Take a look at Apache's [`Tuple`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html) class.
- You should be able to modify the structure of the array through the method itself without the need of returning it. You can use this to your advantage and have a method which only needs to return 1 value. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231042/java-arrays-sort) previous SO post for more information.